# Angular2 - Mocking up Angular2-toaster for Jasmine Unit testing

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing, angular2-toaster

More Generalize the question - How to mock up and external library used in Angular2

In my application i am using [Angular2-toaster](https://github.com/Stabzs/Angular2-Toaster) for popup messages. In order write unit test suite(Jasmine)to one of the component, I tried to mock up the toaster response with following code,

```
@Component({
selector: 'test-component',
template: '<toaster-container [toasterconfig]="toasterconfig"></toaster-container>',
})
export class TestComponent {
    toasterService: ToasterService;

constructor(toasterService: ToasterService) {
    this.toasterService = toasterService;
}

public toasterconfig: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({ showCloseButton: true, tapToDismiss: false, timeout: 0, toastContainerId: 1 });
public toasterconfig2: ToasterConfig = new ToasterConfig({ showCloseButton: true, tapToDismiss: false, timeout: 0, toastContainerId: 2 });
}
```

And added in declarations

```
declarations: [RouterLinkStubDirective, TestComponent],
```

But end up with errors

```
    Error: Error in ./ToasterContainerComponent class ToasterContainerComponent - inline template:1:34 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'klass.trim') in config/k
ma-test-shim.js (line 19495)
    _toggleClass@webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1280:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43944:27
    webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1257:56 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43921:84
    forEachAddedItem@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3391:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:13459:20
    _applyIterableChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1257:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43921:38
    ngDoCheck@webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43895:48
    detectChangesInInputProps
    detectChangesInternal
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:40
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:53
    detectViewChildrenChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19399:37
    detectChangesInternal
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:40
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:53
    detectViewChildrenChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19399:37
    detectChangesInternal
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:40
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:53
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7398:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:17466:38
    _tick@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:194:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9213:50
    webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:208:45 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9227:59
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6715:32
    onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8344:46
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6714:41
    onInvoke@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6206:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:16274:48
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6714:41
    run@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6597:50
    run@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6096:46 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:16164:70
    detectChanges@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:208:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9227:33
    webpack:///src/app/common/sample-search-widget/sample-search-widget-component.spec.ts:113:29 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:51370:31
    execute@webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:823:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9842:29
    webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:910:32 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9929:57
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6715:32
    onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8344:46
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6714:41
    run@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6597:50
    webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8550:38
    webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:91:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9110:36
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6715:32
    onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8642:46
    onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8341:48
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6714:41
    run@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6597:50
    webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:86:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:9105:33
    webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:8631:47
    invokeTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6748:41
    runTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6637:58
    invoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:6818:41
    webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:970:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:7453:31

    x Update trimmed value to model on blur of sample name
      Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 7 0.0.0)
    Error: Error in ./ToasterContainerComponent class ToasterContainerComponent - inline template:1:34 caused by: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
        at NgClass._toggleClass (webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1280:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43944:27)
        at webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1257:56 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43921:72
        at DefaultIterableDiffer.forEachAddedItem (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3391:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:13459:18)
        at NgClass._applyIterableChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1257:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43921:22)
        at NgClass.ngDoCheck (webpack:///~/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js:1231:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:43895:27)
        at Wrapper_NgClass.detectChangesInInputProps (/CommonModule/NgClass/wrapper.ngfactory.js:38:18)
        at _View_ToasterContainerComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/ToasterModule/ToasterContainerComponent/component.ngfactory.js:69:21)
        at _View_ToasterContainerComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:19)
        at _View_ToasterContainerComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:49)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19399:24)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/DynamicTestModule/SampleSearchWidgetComponent/component.ngfactory.js:596:8)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent0.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:19)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:49)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent_Host0.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19399:24)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/DynamicTestModule/SampleSearchWidgetComponent/host.ngfactory.js:45:8)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19373:19)
        at _View_SampleSearchWidgetComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:19478:49)
```

I am not sure following the proper way ! ,

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was a defect in the library itself (see https://github.com/Stabzs/Angular2-Toaster/issues/111) due to a missing elvis operator in the template.

If the titleClass or messageClass properties were null and the Angular runtime attempted to trim either property, the above error would be thrown.

This is currently fixed in versions 4.0.0 and higher of the library.